# Where are my photos saved?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, files, photos

I want to categorize/reorganize the photos in my gallery.  I feel like I've been all over the place in ASTRO, looking them, but I can't seem to find them.  I see my downloads, and some other photo folders I've moved stuff to while plugged in to my computer, but not the photos I've taken with the camera.

I've checked `/mnt/sdcard/dcim`, but all it has are three directories: Camera (empty), Icons (empty) and .thumbnails (full of cryptic cache files).  Same story at `/sdcard/dcim` (I think those two are symlinked).

Where are my photos?

If it makes a difference, I'm on an HTC Incredible.

*edit*

In my camera settings, it is set to save photos to the phone's memory, not my sd card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, found them!

`/emmc/DCIM`

Then most of them are in the `100MEDIA` sub directory.

Answer (score 2):

Your photos should be in the DCIM folder.  I have an HTC EVo and all photos from my camera are in `/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA/`.  I doubt this would help but maybe you should try another file manager.

Try taking a photo and then go to your `DCIM` directory to see if any new folders or images are there.

It looks like you solved your issue!  Just so others have a method to help themselves if they get stuck i'm adding this to my answer:

If you can view any photos in HTC photo app you can long press on the photo and select the `Details` option.  This should provide you with a `File path`

Comment: No luck.  Same as `/mnt/sdcard/dcim`.  I think the two are symlinked.

Comment: Yeah i figured as much but I thought it was worth a shot. Question: when you take a photo can you see it when you select the `photo` button next to the `shutter` button?

Comment: See the bottom part of my revised answer - that might help.